# Retrieve all groups for a member using Google APIs Client Library for PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I am using the Google APIs Client Library for PHP but I do not see a function to Retrieve all groups for a member yet it exists in the Directory API:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey=user key

Is it missing?

Has somebody figured out how to do this using the PHP Library?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the groups.list() method which is the same method you use to list all groups in the Google Apps account. The only difference is you specify the userKey attribute to scope the results down to groups that a given user is a member of:

```
$optParams = array(
  'customer' => 'my_customer',
  'userKey' => 'john@example.com'
);
$results = $service->groups->listGroups($optParams);
```